# Knockd not executing the knock command

Tags: linux, networking, security, firewall, arch-linux

I am trying to setup knock daemon, however it does not seem to execute the knock command. To debug the issue, I used this simple configuration, which is slightly edited example from the documentation:

```
[options]
        logfile = /var/log/knockd.log
[openSSH]
        sequence    = 7000,8000,9000
        seq_timeout = 10
        tcpflags    = syn
        command     = /usr/bin/touch /tmp/knock
[closeSSH]
        sequence    = 9000,8000,7000
        seq_timeout = 10
        tcpflags    = syn
        command     = /usr/bin/rm /tmp/knock
```

I can even prove that the knock is detecting the packets sent with `knock -v 192.168.0.2 7000 8000 9000` by running the knockd in non-daemon mode and logging the output as follows `sudo knockd -c /etc/knockd.conf -ienp2s0 -Dv > log`. The contents of `log` file are as follows:

```
config: new section: 'options'
config: log file: /var/log/knockd.log
config: new section: 'openSSH'
config: openSSH: sequence: 7000:tcp,8000:tcp,9000:tcp
config: openSSH: seq_timeout: 10
config: tcp flag: SYN
config: openSSH: start_command: /usr/bin/touch /tmp/knock
config: new section: 'closeSSH'
config: closeSSH: sequence: 9000:tcp,8000:tcp,7000:tcp
config: closeSSH: seq_timeout: 10
config: tcp flag: SYN
config: closeSSH: start_command: /usr/bin/rm /tmp/knock
ethernet interface detected
listening on enp2s0...
-------- snip -------
2024-00-11 13:08:17: tcp: 192.168.0.182:34892 -> 192.168.0.2:7000 74 bytes
2024-00-11 13:08:17: tcp: 192.168.0.182:49042 -> 192.168.0.2:8000 74 bytes
2024-00-11 13:08:17: tcp: 192.168.0.182:47252 -> 192.168.0.2:9000 74 bytes
waiting for child processes...
closing...
```

And no file gets created in `/tmp/knock`. What am I missing?

Comment: Also at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/766658/117549 (has one answer at the moment).